# Unable to to Import folder MS Access Export Text Wizard Error

Tags: ms-access

When I perform a query on a database and try to export the results to a text (CSV) I get the following error:

"The wizard is unable to import the folder 'Query3'.  This is usually
because the name of the folder contains a space and a SQL keyword
(such as the 'Deleted Items' folder, which contains a space and the
word 'Delete'.  You may, however, link to this table."

How can I export my query to a csv without this error.

Comment: So does the stated condition apply? Edit question to show the folder path string.

Comment: Error messages should be posted a text, not just images. Images can be hard to read.

Comment: `Query3` sounds like the name of the query, you try to export, not the name of the destination folder.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the event.  I was new to access.  It has been many months and would like this question taken off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solved this issue by running the designed query, saving the query, then exporting to text file.